# In LibreOffice pasting columns changed (does not work right) Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: libreoffice, paste

Normally when I select the contents of a table column in writer and copy it I can then highlight the same column in another document, and paste it in.  All of the rows fill in as expected; each row is identical.

Today the results have not only changed they are annoyingly ridiculous:

Now when I try to past the column each row contains the whole column separated as rows within borders and all!!!

Since the tables are Identical in both doc's, I tried to copy and past the whole table replacing the one I want to overwrite (Highlight the whole table-paste), contents borders and all (Also used to work as expected), Now I get Pages of rows and columns, what were 4 columns with 6 rows each are now 4 columns with 4 tables each spanning pages!!!

I have made no settings changes, but do software updates when asked by the OS, and that may have caused it.

I did figure out to past the copied table into a blank space, and delete the other one I can not past into, or else past each row of each column separately, but neither are good solutions, logical nor efficient.

Sad thing is that seemingly every month LibreOffice flips out in one way or another!

Comment: Looks more like a LibreOffice problem. Also, some images would be helpful. It is difficult to understand your problem otherwise

Comment: Can you try "paste special" in the edit menu.I am using Libreoffice Version: 5.1.4.2 - Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1. If I choose "paste special" Formatted Text [RTF] it produces the problem you are describing.If I choose Libre Office or Unformatted text paste options it does not.I wonder if your paste is defaulting to the RTF paste type for some reason.

Comment: Thanx linuxbin, but I tried every past option available, and it does the same thing, but the text format does change (font...).

I did notice that in the paste menu I used to have two options:  Formated and unformatted text.  Now I have unformatted text and More options that opens a pop up box with 2 new entries:  HTML and formatted RTF.  I have not needed the menu for months.

I am using LibreOffice  1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 16.4.

Comment: Sorry Ron, But I don't think I could have been any more clear, and yes it sure does look like a LibreOffice problem, but on Ubuntu you get a Canonical altered version, which shows new bugs every time I use it, which is almost daily!

Comment: The Libreoffice user profile is located at /home/user/.config/libreoffice  Try shutting down all libreoffice applications, copy the folder as a backup and then delete the original folder.Launching any libreoffice app should regenerate the profile, so we can eliminate profile corruption.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do that  once again!  There should be a button for it, as it seems to be necessary so darn often!

I will do it, but later; have to finish a job.

Comment: No That did not do it either.  I closed all doc's, and the quick starter and renamed the whole folder, made no difference.

Maybe an update of some shared lib's?  I do not know how to trace that.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Strangely and suddenly out of the blue while using the "past into blank space" workaround I mentioned above all day, the look of the highlighted data just changed and no longer filled in cells completely and changed to a narrower selection with some space around it.  I copied the column, highlighted a column to overwrite, and it pasted as it should!  The only thing I did between it not working and working again was restart my email client Evolution because it too gets whacked out sometimes.

I can not post this as an answer because I have no idea how it happened.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Well the odd behavior came back,  then it worked right for a while only to return again.  It is intermittent, which probably just makes it that much more difficult to troubleshoot.